# AngularJS directive template doesn't start injected service function/how to get the clicked attrs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am having problems with being abble to execute a function from a service in an onclick event in the template of my directive (inside an ng-repeat).

I think the ng-repeat adds problems. Actually what I wanted to do was put a *ng-click="downloadNotService.myfunction(file.file, file.id)"* in the button element of the template. But a**lthough my service was injected to the directive it didn't want to fire from the ng-click**. Why is this?

So I tried to do it in link instead. Because the button is in a ng-repeat I couldn't find the element so I added a watch. But now the first time I click it runs once but the second time **the code inside the watch loops** (like 6X, 27X, 31X,...) Why is that?

I also **can't get the value of my-help attribute**. Already tried a bunch of different approaches but it just doesn't work. Also it has to be the **value of the attr inside the clicked button**.

Can anyone help? Where am I going wrong and how could I make better (and most importantly working) code?

```
"use strict";

app.directive('inProgress',
                  function(downloadNotService) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            isActive: "=",
            aantal: "=",
            files: "="
          },
          template: '<div ng-show="isActive"><p style="color: rgb(2,43,81)"><img src="images/loading2.gif" width="25px" height="25px" /> {{aantal}} document{{aantal>1&&"en worden"||" wordt"}} klaargemaakt</p></div>'+
            '<div><ul ng-controller="Ctrl"><li ng-repeat="file in dlService.file"><a href="{{file.file}}">{{file.id}}</a> <button class="btn" my-help={{file.file}}>X</button></li></ul>',
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.$watch(function(){
              elem.find('button').on('click', function(){
                console.log("you clicked button with " + attrs.myHelp);
                downloadNotService.myFunction();
                });
            });
          }
      }  
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$watch` like that is incorrect. The `$watch` function is called every time there is a digest cycle to see if the value that it returns has changed.

That means every time you enter a digest cycle you will be adding on click handler to the button, resulting in your observed behavior of multiple calls to the on click function per click.

You can just pass the file to your function. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="file in dlService.file"><a href="{{file.file}}">{{file.id}}</a> <button class="btn" my-help={{file.file}} ng-click="clicked(file)">X</button></li></ul>',
    controller: function($scope, downloadService) {
      $scope.dlService = downloadService;
      $scope.clicked = function(file) {
        console.log("you clicked button with " + JSON.stringify(file, null, 2));
      };
    }
  };
});

app.service('downloadService', function() {
  this.file = [{
    file: 'a',
    id: 1
  }, {
    file: 'b',
    id: 2
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>

  <some-directive></some-directive>

</div>
```

See console for output.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the watch problem. Actually after I typed this question I realized why I couldn't use the service function in ng-click. By pointing it to the scope in link it worked. Feel really stupid now. Thanks for showing how I could do it also.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.